# SQL Server 2008 CASE Logic in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, field

Hello again SQL Server 2008 gurus.

I need to apply the following rules to the setting of a worker's start and end times for their work day (hourly employees) in a `SELECT` statement. I apologize in advance for my SQL ignorance.

1. The rule is to set their start time to a value stored in a table field for that worker, if they login on or before their start time (a time stored in the worker `starttime` column) and therefore get credit for starting at their start time.

   If they log out within a 10 minute period before or anytime after their end time stored in a column for the worker, they get credit for their full day, another value stored in a column of the worker table, otherwise they are penalized some percentage of an hour, i.e. their log out time rounded to .25 of an hour less closest to the time they logged out. i.e. if they are set to log out at 4:30, and they log out at 4:18, their log out time is 4:15. If they log out at  4:20, and are set to log out at 4:30, their log out time is 4:30.
2. The first rule applies to all hourly employees where their workday hours is less than or equal to their expected workday value. The caveat is, for those where overtime is ok (a bit value set to 1). If overtime is permitted, the number of billable hours can exceed the full day value stored for them, and therefore the value of their logout - login time can exceed their fullday value.

   The question is, can these rules be calculated in the SELECT statement and if so can I get some help with the code?

The columns containing the information are:

```
    worker.startime (TIME)
    worker.endtime  (TIME)
    worker.overtimeallowed (BIT)
    worker.workdayhours (decimal (12,2))
    worker.penaltyvalue (decimal (12,2))
```

If it requires a UDF or stored procedure (since I'm using the Telerik ReportViewer) I'm not sure it would be supported, but that's probably another question.

So far I've gotten some help with applying some CASE logic - calculating whether a worker get's credit for their 1/2 lunch. The code that was supplied works as promised. This, I believe may be an extension to that logic - so I'll provide the code I have here:

```
      -- for testing purposes only.
      DECLARE @StartDate AS DateTime
      SET @StartDate = CAST('03/25/2012' AS DATE)
      DECLARE @EndDate AS DateTime
      SET @EndDate = CAST('04/10/2012' AS DATE)

      SELECT 
      w.Firstname 
     ,w.Lastname 
     ,wf.Login
     ,wf.logout
     ,ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, wf.Login, wf.Logout) AS DECIMAL)/60,2) 
     - CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, wf.Login, wf.Logout) < w.MinimumHours THEN      
          w.LunchDeduction
        ELSE
        0
       END AS [Hours Credited]
     FROM Workers AS w 
     JOIN Workflow AS wf 
     ON wf.LoggedInWorkerid = w.ID 
     JOIN Roles AS r
     ON w.RoleID = r.RoleID
     WHERE (r.Descript = 'Hourly')
     AND wf.Login >= @StartDate AND wf.Logout <= @EndDate 
     ORDER BY w.Lastname, w.Firstname
```

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it can all be done in a query.  Like most problems, try breaking it down.  Cut'n'paste your existing `CASE` and modify it to check the "10 minute" rule and output a flag.  Then keep adding one layer at a time.  You'll have it soon enough.

Comment: In most jurisdictions, if an employee clocks in early, you MUST pay them for the time, even if overtime is not approved. They worked, they get paid. Period. Yes, it's a problem, but not one you deal with by withholding pay. HR has a talk with the manager about setting expectations, and the manager has a talk with the employee about when they show up and clock in; if expectations still aren't met then management starts using the disciplinary process to enforce compliance. But if they clocked in and worked, they get paid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample select dealing with constraints you described. CTEs create tables for testing purposes. Main query shows the calculations. You have worked with datediffs and dateadds so there is no mistery. If you haven't use % before, it is [modulo operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) used to round time to 15 minutes.

```
;with worker (ID, overtime, startTime, endTime) as
(
    select 1, 1, CAST ('08:30' as time), CAST ('16:30' as time)
    union all
    select 2, 0, CAST ('08:30' as time), CAST ('16:30' as time)
    union all
    select 3, 0, CAST ('08:30' as time), CAST ('16:30' as time)
),
-- Test table of workflows
wf (workerID, login, logout) as
(
    select 1, CAST ('2012-03-11 08:20' as datetime), CAST ('2012-03-11 19:33' as datetime)
    union all
    select 2, CAST ('2012-03-11 08:50' as datetime), CAST ('2012-03-11 16:20' as datetime)
    union all
    select 3, CAST ('2012-03-11 08:22' as datetime), CAST ('2012-03-11 16:18' as datetime)
)
select wf.workerID,
  wf.login,
  wf.logout,
  --  if starttime > login return startTime else login
  case when DATEDIFF(MI, w.startTime, cast (wf.login as time)) < 0 
    then cast(CAST (wf.login AS date) AS datetime) + w.startTime
    else wf.login
  end roundedLogin,
  case when w.overtime = 1 -- Round to 15 minutes whenever finished
         OR
         -- Round to 15 minutes if left ten or more minutes before endTime
            DATEDIFF(MI, cast (wf.logout as time), dateadd (MI, -10, w.endTime)) > 0 
    then dateadd (MI, -(DATEPART (MI, wf.logout) % 15), wf.logout)
    -- stop at endTime if overtime = 0 OR left job at apropriate time
    else cast(CAST (wf.logout AS date) AS datetime) + w.endTime
  end roundedLogout
from worker w 
  inner join wf 
     on w.ID = wf.workerID
```

There will be a problem with this approach. When you start to integrate mathematics into original query you will notice that you have to write expressions evaluating roundedLogin and roundedLogout again to calculate billable hours. You cannot reuse alias defined in the same scope, but you can create derived table or view or even calculated fields. View returning columns from workflows and all additional expressions would probably be the best.

Using this view in other queries would simplify things by encapsulating logic at one place.

Comment: I like this answer Nikola. I've put together a stored proc, but it doesn't have this logic. I can't seem to enter the code I've pieced together with yours, so I guess I have to ask another question. With the power of a stored proc behind the report - I'm assuming I can get a DATEDIFF on the roundedLogin and roundedLogout, which would be wonderful.

Comment: Yes you can, but at present you will have to repeat expressions each time you use it, even in the same query. Hence a suggestion to create a view on workflow with this two columns added.

Comment: I've been playing with this for a while now trying to  figure it out. Why would wf.logout value of 2012-03-05 19:20:45.000 get set in roundLogout to 1900-01-01 16:30:00.000 using your -->CASE WHEN w.OvertimeOk = 1 OR
DATEDIFF(MI, wf.logout, dateadd (MI, 10, w.endTime)) > 0 
THEN dateadd (MI, -(DATEPART (MI, wf.logout) % 15), wf.logout)<-- when w.OvertimeOk = 0? This is the value set for every record where w.OvertimeOk = 0 however it works perfectly when it hits an OvertimeOk = 1.

Comment: Whenever a comparation is done wf.login and wf.logout should be truncated to time only. I'm gonna edit my sample.

Comment: @CliffRobinson I've been hasty, completely ignoring date portion in login and logout fields. Try it now.

Comment: this is very close. I've yet to determine what you did, but I will study it. I see a couple of rows that maybe are a special case - not sure. For example. A logout of 14:29 gets a roundedlogout of 14:15. I don't think the worker would appreciate the missing 15 minutes of pay :)

Comment: I round down. If you would like to round by half add 8 minutes to login/logout date prior to % operation.

Comment: Not sure how, but this is my stab in the dark which includes your code -->  dateadd (MI, -(DATEPART (MI, DATEADD(MI,8,wf.logout)) % 15), wf.logout)<-- the DATEADD(MI,8,wf.logout) is my addition. Is this the right idea?

Comment: I think that this should be OK. Now 15:37 shoul become 15:45; truncate will leave it at 15:45. 15:36 will be 15:44, 15:30 when truncated.